# Is "Zone" different among projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#zones_and_clusters), it says a "zone" could be mapped to different cluster for different projects but is it true that a zone may map to a different cluster among projects?
I've never seen a zone mapping difference across projects. Also, since [each zone provides different machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available), I'm not even sure if a zone could be mapped to different clusters among projects.
If it does, is there a way to find out which cluster my zone is mapped to like the one in [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-map-cross-account-availability-zones/)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A cluster, as defined, is simply a set of physical servers, networks, disk, cooling. In short, a datacenter. It's impossible to know, it's google internal management.

A zone comes on top of one or several clusters. If the initial cluster (aka datacenter) is too small, Google can have chosen to expend it and if it's not possible to add another one. But at user point of view, it's invisible!

Google try to locate all the projects of the same organization in the same cluster, especially for security and performance reason in case of VPC peering or Shared VPC. However, it's not guaranteed. But, because your don't know this, you can't check it.

For example, if 2 projects are on 2 different clusters in the same region, there isn't issue. But if you create a VPC peering, it's not optimized. To solve this, Google can migrate Compute Engine from a cluster to another one, even without stopping the VM (it's called ["live migration"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration)), you aren't able to see anything of this VM placement.

Generally the cluster is consistent for a project. In case of huge resources usage, it could be different (HPC for example, or with requirement of 10k+ CPUs), but Googlers must have more detail in this case if you are a big CPU consumer

---

I tried to create a GKE regional cluster in europe-west3, with N2 cpu type, only available in 2 of the 3 zone and I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks guillaume!


According to google's documentation, what you explained perfectly makes sense.


However, when I try to create a compute engine VM on different zones within the same region, the zone name and the available machine types described here always match. For instance, europe-north1-a and europe-north1-c have M1 as available machine types and europe-north1-b doesn't. If a zone is mapped to a different cluster which has different machine types available, wouldn't the zone shown in the console differ from the one described in the documentation?

Comment: Hmmm, your question is interesting. I think that the cluster isn't a problem because it is abstracted by the Zone. But, the interesting part is: If I define a multi-zonal service (Managed instance group or GKE cluster), I would like to have 3 zones. But if only 2 supports my CPU type, what happens? What's the behavior? Only a High Availability on 2 zones? Another machine type is used? I will dig into it.

Comment: I'm still confused about how the zone name appears on my console.
So in the case of europe-north1, the europe-north1-b cluster doesn't have M1 machine type as documented. If a zone user sees maps to a different cluster, wouldn't that user see europe-north1-a or europe-north1-c having no M1 machine type (in that case, from the user's perspective, the documentation is wrong because he/she sees europe-north1-a or europe-north1-c has no M1.)?